# ASP.NET Login box positioning

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2005 C#. I have a login box in my .aspx page, but I can't find the parameter I have to set too position it in the middle of my webpage.

I have tried using `&nbsp;` but it did not work as well.

Below is my code for my login box:

```
<asp:login id="Login1" runat="server" font-size="Large" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#333333" DestinationPageUrl="~/Common/Default.aspx" DisplayRememberMe="False" FailureText="Login failed" RememberMeSet="False">
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
    <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
   <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
    <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:login>
```

Anyone knows how to position login control?

Thank you

Comment: why you are not using table or div tag to place it in center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <div align="center">
    <asp:login id="Login1" runat="server" font-size="Large" BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
                BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#333333" 
                DestinationPageUrl="~/Common/Default.aspx" DisplayRememberMe="False" 
                FailureText="Login failed" RememberMeSet="False" EnableTheming="True" >
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
       <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:login>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to place it inside a div or table, and align that to the centre of the screen. Another way is to see the html output of the login control and use the class name or ID of the control in CSS to align it to the centre of the screen. There might not be any property in loginbox to do that itself but you will come to work around it and use HTML basics.

Answer (score 0):

Its Very easy try this! Only for VS2005

Just select your LogIn control, and then select

Layout menu -> Position -> absolute...

Now you can Drag your LogIn control...